# Stacked highchart in php

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I am trying to get stacked highcharts in my php code. The variables used are returning proper data as you can see in the error graph attached.This is my code:

```
$(function(){
var chart1;
function setChart(name,data,stack)
{
chart1.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
chart1.series[0].remove();
chart1.addSeries({
});
}
 chart1=new Highcharts.Chart({
              chart:{
                 renderTo: 'container1',
                     type: 'column',
                     backgroundColor: "#F7F7F7"
                     },
                  title:{
                 text:'Issue Followup'
                     },
                  xAxis:{
                 categories:[<?php echo $cat ?>]
                     },
                  yAxis:{
                 min: 0,
                     title:{
                    text:'No. of issues'
                        },
                     },
                  tooltip:{
                 headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                     footerFormat: '</table>',
                     shared: true,
                     useHTML: true
                     },
                  plotOption:{
                 column:{
                    stacking:'normal',
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                        }
               },
                  series:[{
                    showInLegend: false,
                        name:['Fixed'],
                        data:[<?php echo $cn1 ?>],
                        stack:'stack'},
                     {
                       showInLegend: false,
                           name:['Open'],
                           data:[<?php echo $cn2 ?>],
                           stack:'stack'
                           }]
 });
      });
```

However instead of getting a stacked graph, I am getting a grouped graph. Please tell me what am I doing wrong here.
[image: Grouped Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
plotOption:{
```

to:

```
plotOptions:{
```